# Rendering performance in d3

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I am creating a data visualisation program using d3, and I have encountered a performance problem while trying to set the opacity of lots of element.

I have event that is called, when the user is changing some data, when this event is fired I compute the opacity for each edges,nodes and text nodes and change them accordingly.

for example -

```
function onEvent() {
  edges.style("opacity", computeOpacity);
  edges.style("stroke", computeStroke);

  nodes.style("opacity", computeOpacity);
  textNodes.style("opacity", computeOpacity);

}
```

When I have lot of elements (edges/nodes/text nodes counts are greater than 700), the UX is very sluggish and slow.

I checked chrome timeline - and see there is a recalculate style, after that a paint (which paints the all "svg" element) and 2/3 composite layers.

What I can do in order to improve the performance of my code?
The opacity and stroke computation for each edge/node/text node is very important, and is very cheap operation - checking some properties and doing simple Math.max calculation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the actual computations, but the rendering of the SVG. As such, there's nothing you can really do in D3 to improve it. However, here are a few things you can try.

- If you can filter the number of elements shown, do that.
- If the change in opacity for a particular element would be very small, don't change it as it won't be visible.
- Replace your elements with simpler ones if possible, in particular straight `path`s with `line`.
- Use Canvas instead of SVG.

What's possible and what works will depend on your particular application.

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you for your answer, I will check the second and third thing on the list.
What is the simplest way for rendering a d3 force layout in canvas?

Comment: `stroke-opacity` and `fill-opacity` are usually cheaper to compute than `opacity`, so if you can use those instead that might be an option.

Comment: I changed the opacity for particular elements, and my ui is still slow, I saw that I have 14k nodes (which 97% are svg).. I am looking for library like dc.js that works on canvas.

Comment: FWIW, D3 isn't SVG specific. It works with canvas just as well -- the only "problem" is that most of the examples use SVG.

Comment: Lars, d3 under the hood uses svg for it's drawing

Comment: No, it doesn't. Most of the example you find do but there's (almost) nothing specific to SVG apart from a few helper functions that you don't have to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn on "show paint rectangles" in the chrome dev tools settings you can see which parts are being repainted.

Using this I found that when I altered the stroke width on hover that it slowed down the paint rendering dramatically and oddly the the bottom right caused the entire page to repaint.

Now when having the same stroke width set before the hover it has speed up.

You may discover something odd in yours.